# Using and instance of a class on two forms

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I am struggling to get my head around the following.
I current have three forms, my main and one main class.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class frmSuppliers : Form
{
    public frmSuppliers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class frmCustomers : Form
{
    public frmCustomers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In my main program I have:

```
 public class Program
 {
        public StockControl StockSystem = new StockControl("The Book Shop", 20);
 }
```

I want to be able to access the methods from StockControl in frmSuppliers and frmMain.

I know this may be a N00b question - but its been bugging me all day!

Comment: Is StockControl a "Singleton"? i.e. is there only one "StockControl" per instance of your application?

Comment: @NominSim Yes - within this class it contains a list of type customer, type supplier and type product.

Comment: @thatnerdoverthere You can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for how to implement a Singleton if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass it to the other forms as a constructor parameter, then store it in a private field.

Comment: A coded example of this would be great, I think I know what your talking about, howver I am unsure if I am thinking of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

declare it static

```
public static StockControl StockSystem = new StockControl("The Book Shop", 20);
```

and use as

```
Program.StockSystem
```

Comment: Don't declare it static :P Pass it around instead

Comment: @Patrick Both making it static and passing around might work - depending on the situation.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev: Of course it will work. But making it static is bad advice since everyone can access it then. It's like putting the key to your home out on the lawn for everyone to use.

Comment: @Patrick That seems to be specifically what the OP has asked for. (Though I agree with you that the OP may not *know* that this is not a great idea).

Comment: @Patrick - at the current level of this program, security is not that essential.

Comment: @thatnerdoverthere It's not a matter of security, it's a matter of scaleability, and also of developing good programming practices early.  If you learn things the wrong way it will only make learning how to do them properly that much harder down the road.

Comment: @Servy I with what you are saying about good establishing good development skills early - just whats the alternatives to public static?

Comment: @thatnerdoverthere There is another answer to this question that has a substantially higher score.  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @thatnerdoverthere Oh, and I notice that you tagged the question "OOP".  Using a public static variable would be poor object oriented programming; the data should just be passed around as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a field of type StockControl to each of your forms, and make it public, or add getter/setter to it. This means adding the following lines to each one of your forms:

```
private StockControl _stockCtrl;
public StockControl StockCtrl
{
   get { return _stockCtrl; }
   set { _stockCtrl = value; }
}
```

The in the cod of each form you can access your StockControl. But it will be empty (i.e. null) if you don't assign it something. This is something I'd do before opening the form. If you are in your main method:

```
frmSuppliers frmToOpen = new frmSuppliers();
frmSuppliers.StockCtrl = StockSystem;
frmSuppliers.Show();
```