# Accessing objects in several forms in C#

Tags: c#, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using and instance of a class on two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916314/using-and-instance-of-a-class-on-two-forms)

As I am pretty new to OOP - especially with Visual C# - I have a problem understanding the following:

A Windows Forms application has several forms. They all shall have access to a object `Client` (for communicating with a server) created in one of the forms. But how do I make exactly this object instance available in the other forms?

Comment: Can't you pass the object to required form classes via constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Client public static in the form parent form and access it from other forms. You have to make it thread safe if access synchronously.

Public will make it available to other forms where as make a single instance for all forms. To make it public static.

```
public static Client client.
```

To access it from other forms, assuming client is in Form1 and being accessed from other form.

```
Client client1 = Form1.client;
```

Comment: Or maybe place it in a static class in the same namespace, but not tied to a form eg: `Variables.Client`.

Comment: Yes @MatthewRz if it is possible then it is even better.